# atoi() Giving Output as 0 Despite the string having Integers

Tags: c

Here is the code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <math.h>

 int main() //main function
 {   
     // Body of the main function starts here.
     double c5,c0,semitone_ratio,frequency; //Defining the middle C, the lowest  note in MIDI, the ratio and frequency.

     char message[256];
     int midinote = 0;
     char* result;
     semitone_ratio = pow(2,1/12.0); //Calculating the semitone ratio.
     c5 = 220.0 * pow(semitone_ratio, 3); //Calculating the Middle C Frequency using A5 = 440 Hz and raising it up 3 notes.
     c0 = c5 * pow(0.5,5);             //Calculating C0 by shifting it down 5 octaves

     //User Interface
     printf("Enter MIDI note (0-127) : \n");
     scanf("%s", message);
     printf("%s", message);

     if(result == NULL){
         printf("There was an error reading the input");
         return 1;
     }

     if(message[0] = '\0') {
         printf("No input detected");
         return 1;
     }

     midinote = atoi(message);

     if(midinote <0){
         printf("Sorry - %s is a bad MIDI note number", message);
         return 1;
     }

     if(midinote > 127)
     {
         printf("Sorry - %s is above the range needed", message);
     }

     frequency = c0 * pow(semitone_ratio, midinote);
     printf("The frequency  for the %d MIDI note is %f\n",midinote,frequency);

     return 0;
}
```

The problem here is that despite whatever message I enter the O/P is always 0. I have tried `scanf()` instead of `gets()`, result instead of message (`char *` instead of `char[]`->handling the const problem) and yet the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: `result` is tested for, but never assigned a value. Your compiler should have warned you.

Comment: the `gets()` function has been depreciated for years and is completely removed in the latest C standard.  Suggest using `fgets()` for reading a line of input.

Comment: regarding this line: `scanf("%s", message);` 1) When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the '%s' input conversion specifier, always use a `max length` modifier (that is one less than the size of the input buffer) to assure the input does not overflow the input buffer, resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest: `scanf("%255s", message);`.

Comment: the variable `result` looks to be something left over from when `gets()` was being used.  Of course when you correct the code to use `result = fgets( message, sizeof(message), stdin);` then all those problems will go away.

Comment: If you really want to use `scanf()` to input the 'midinote' value, then write the call to `scanf()` similar to: `if( 1 != scanf( "%d", &midinote )) { // handle input error }`  then code the checks for the range

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`   I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: regarding this kind of line: `if(message[0] = '\0') {`  if you code such statements, placing the literal on the left, then the compiler will catch the errors rather than you having to spend your time and aggravation debugging the problem.  I.E. `if( '\0' == message[0] ) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the culprit:

`if(message[0] = '\0') {`

You are actually resetting `message` to an empty string. Whereas, you wanted to check whether the `message` is empty or not.

Use `==` for comparison:

`if(message[0] == '\0') {`

Answer (score 5):

```
if (message[0] = '\0') {
    printf("No input detected");
    return 1;
}
```

Use `==`.

```
if (message[0] == '\0') {
    printf("No input detected");
    return 1;
}
```